# How to display the content of a DynamoDB table

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cli

My DynamoDB table has the following attritubes

```
sales_id: hashkey
created_date: rangekey
sales_employee_id:IndexedHashKey
```

I am trying to get all the data of the table Sales just as in MySQL

```
  select * from Sales
```

How can I query DynamoDB. I am trying with the below AWS CLI query but it fails everytime with the below message

```
aws dynamodb get-item --table-name Sales --key '{"sales_id":{"N":"1"}}'
```

Below is the error message

```
An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the GetItem operation: The provided key element does not match the schema
```

The node js code below also throws the same error

```
  var getSalesDetails = function(user_id, callback) {

var params = {
    TableName: "Sales",
    Key:{
        ":sales_id":{"N":"1"},
        ":created_date":{"S": "2018-01-22"}
    }
};
docClient.get(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) console.log(err); // an error occurred
    else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
};
```

Comment: In the AWS CLI command you haven't provided a `created_date` query parameter. In the Node js code, it seems you are passing both `sales_id` and `created_date` as a partition `Key`. Shouldn't you provide the `created_date` separate from the `Key`?

Comment: Double check your datatype of hash and range

Comment: Data type for sales_id is N and range is S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have defined the key attributes with below data type, the following code should work. The `docClient` should automatically derive the data type based on the variable value.

> sales_id: hashkey - Number
>
> created_date: rangekey - String

Removed the explicit data type provided in the Key attribute.

```
var params = {
    TableName: "Sales",
    Key:{
        ":sales_id": 1,
        ":created_date": "2018-01-22"
    }
};
docClient.get(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) console.log(err); // an error occurred
    else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
};
```

Comment: It is not working, I have tried this. Will it produce this error if an incorrect value is passed to key maybe sales_id where it is not existing

Comment: no, it won't throw error if the key is not present in table.